# Compile a dust template that has an index helper

Tags: dust.js

I am trying to compile a dust template that has an index helper ({@idx}{.}{/idx}) using grunt-dust. For some reason, the helper is not getting evaluated. Is there an explicit step to enable helpers in the Gruntfile? My Gruntfile configuration has dust.options.wrapper set to *false*.

```
<ul>
   {#day.hours}
   <li id="id{@idx}{.}{/idx}" >
      <div>{startTime} {@idx}{.}{/idx}</div>
   </li>
   {/day.hours}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`grunt-dust` task generates `dust-runtime.js` file which includes `dust-core.js` only.

In order for helpers to work you need to include [dust-helpers.js](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/blob/master/dist/dust-helpers.js) along with `dust-runtime.js` (or [dust-core.js](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/dist/dust-core.js) which is the same as `dust-runtine.js`).

Note, `dust-helpers` needs to be included during render time only, no need to include it for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using grunt-dust myself, but you could try using $idx instead of {@idx}{.}{/idx}

This is a quick solution, but I'll look into why grunt-dust doesn't evaluate helpers.